# Chainlink PriceFeed Not Working

Tags: solidity, chainlink, chainlink-vrf

I'm writing a smart contract for school fee management. but when I call

> get pay

the function is showing this. why they not converting ether to USD with price feed chain link contract!.

[image]

Contract is here!

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;



import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";


contract UMFS {

address ADMIN;
 

struct FEEDATA {
    string Name ; 
    uint256 reg_ID;
    uint256 FeeAmount;
    bool Paid ;
}
 
mapping(uint256 => FEEDATA) StudentDATA;
 

 constructor () {
      ADMIN = msg.sender;
 }

function SetStudentData( uint256 _reg_ID , string memory _name,uint256 _FeeAmount ) public {
       StudentDATA[_reg_ID].Name = _name;
       StudentDATA[_reg_ID].reg_ID = _reg_ID;
       StudentDATA[_reg_ID].FeeAmount = _FeeAmount ;
       StudentDATA[_reg_ID].Paid = false;
}

function SET_NE_ADMIN(address _Admin) public OnlyAdmin {
    ADMIN = _Admin;
}


function GET_FEE_STATUS (uint256 _reg_ID) public view  returns(bool value) {
     require(StudentDATA[_reg_ID].reg_ID == _reg_ID,"NOT STU");
       return StudentDATA[_reg_ID].Paid;
}

function getFee(uint256 _reg_ID) public  view returns(uint256){
     require(StudentDATA[_reg_ID].reg_ID == _reg_ID,"NOT STU");
    return getConverstionRate(StudentDATA[_reg_ID].FeeAmount);
    //    return StudentDATA[_reg_ID].FeeAmount;
}

function GetPay(uint256 _reg_ID) public payable{
    require(StudentDATA[_reg_ID].reg_ID == _reg_ID,"NOT STU");
    require(StudentDATA[_reg_ID].Paid == false ,"Alread Paid!");
    require(getConverstionRate(msg.value) >= StudentDATA[_reg_ID].FeeAmount , "not engh");
    //    require(msg.value >= StudentDATA[_reg_ID].FeeAmount , "not engh");
      (bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{
            value:  StudentDATA[_reg_ID].FeeAmount
        }("");
      require(success);
    StudentDATA[_reg_ID]. Paid = true;


}

 function getpriceETH() public view returns(uint256){
       AggregatorV3Interface pricefeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306);
       (,int256 answer,,,) = pricefeed.latestRoundData();
       return uint256(answer * 1e10);
    }

   function getConverstionRate(uint256 _EthAmount) internal view returns(uint256) {
        uint256 ethAmount = getpriceETH();
        uint256 ethAmountInUSD = (ethAmount * _EthAmount) / 1e18;
        return ethAmountInUSD;
    }

modifier OnlyAdmin {
    require(msg.sender == ADMIN , "NOT ADMIN!");
    _;
}
```

}

Comment: I think you are failing some requirements from getPaid() are you sure you are seting a value in eth bigger than StudentDATA[_reg_ID].FeeAmount = _FeeAmount?

Comment: yes bro I'm already setting FeeAmount

Comment: can you change getConverstionRate to public/external and call it to check / isolate whether the error is in fetching from the Price Feed or in your implementation of GetPay()?

It may be that the computations in GetPay are more than the standard gas limits set in metamask etc.   we need to isolate which step is failing. If Price Feed is working then the issue is in GetPay.